# Разработка приложений для Windows XP в Visual Studio 2017 + Windows 10?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-xp

Есть потребность в том, чтобы моя программа имела полноценную поддержку Windows XP.

Как реализовать эту поддержку в Visual Studio 2017, которая установлена в среде Windows 10?

Comment: windows xp мертв

Comment: @MikeWaters, так-то да, поддержки нема уже сто лет в обед. Однако множество систем до сих пор висят на этой операционке ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: На каком языке пишете? C#, C++?

Comment: C++. С C# всё проще, просто скачай Framework

Answer (score 1):

1. Установите набор инструментов для построения под WinXP.

Запустите инсталлятор Visual Studio (через пункт "Изменить" в "Программах и компонентах"), на странице "Компоненты" установите галку **Windows XP support for C++**, нажмите "Установить".

2. Измените свойства проекта

На вкладке "Общие" в поле "Набор инструментов платформы" ("Platform toolset") выберите **Visual Studio 2017 - Windows XP (v141_xp)**

3. Не используйте API, которые отсутствуют в Windows XP (например, DWM API, Multimedia Device API, Speech Recognition API, IMAPI, Network List Manager и др.)

Источник: [Configuring Programs for Windows XP](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/configuring-programs-for-windows-xp?view=vs-2017)